# 2 listviews with 2 adapters

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to make an android app with 2 listviews - the main listview shows list of general informations, after row selection the second listview should be shown(with detail informations).
General listview was running correctly, but I have problem with implementation of second listview.
What I tried: I copied code of general listview and changed it(variables, view name,...) to detailed listview, but i get error. 
My code is not very short, so i try to paste important blocks. if something is missing, let me know.

general listview adapter code:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
List<Czoznam> zoznam = new ArrayList<Czoznam>();
LayoutInflater inflater;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Czoznam> aZoznam ) {
    this.context = context;
    this.zoznam=aZoznam;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //TextView and variable definitions here
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
    //textview value assignments here...
    return itemView;
}
```

mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView zoznamListView;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
List<Czoznam> zoznamList = new ArrayList<Czoznam>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
zoznamListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.zozn);
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, zoznamList);
    zoznamListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    zoznamListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
//it works, applications gets here
    }
    });
```

So i copied code shown upper(created ListViewDetailAdapter), changed variables, created layout. and tried to do this:

```
zoznam1ListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.zoznamSprav);
    adapter1 = new ListViewDetailAdapter(this, zoznam1List);
    zoznam1ListView.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

but i get error at second row: adapter1 = new ...

```
error: incompatible types: ListViewDetailAdapter cannot be converted to ListViewAdapter
```

I checked code and I dont think that i forgotten to change some variable in copied sections. Where should I search for error?
Thank you for help.

Comment: Do you by any chance have `ListViewAdapter adapter1`? if so it should be `ListViewDetailAdapter adapter1`;

Comment: yes, you are right. the declaration was wrong. I changed it and now the error disappeared.